# AWS Cloudwatch Monitoring - Migrated the EC2 server in another region

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudwatch

I was using the cloud watch monitoring script (aws-scripts-mon) and it was working fine. but I recently migrated my server to a different region (from Singapore to Mumbai).

now ec2 server is pushing the data to the previous region, even I have changed the default region to Mumbai.

while running this command ./mon-put-instance-data.pl --mem-util --verify --verbose, it shows an endpoint that is of the Singapore region.

No credential methods are specified. Trying default IAM role.
Using IAM role

```
Endpoint: https://monitoring.**ap-southeast-1**.amazonaws.com
Payload: {"MetricData":[{".......................................
```

How can I change this endpoint?

Thank you.

Comment: now ec2 server is pushing the data to the previous region, even I have changed the default region to Mumbai.

while running this command ./mon-put-instance-data.pl --mem-util --verify --verbose, it shows an endpoint that is of the Singapore region.

No credential methods are specified. Trying default IAM role.
Using IAM role <my IAM role name here>
Endpoint: https://monitoring.**ap-southeast-1**.amazonaws.com
Payload: {"MetricData":[{".......................................

How can I change this endpoint?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

From the AWS [doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/monitoring-scripts-intro.html).

> Troubleshoot
>
> The CloudWatchClient.pm module caches instance metadata
> locally. If you create an AMI from an instance where you have run the
> monitoring scripts, any instances launched from the AMI within the
> cache TTL (default: six hours, 24 hours for Auto Scaling groups) emit
> metrics using the instance ID of the original instance. After the
> cache TTL time period passes, the script retrieves fresh data and the
> monitoring scripts use the instance ID of the current instance. To
> immediately correct this, remove the cached data using the following
> command:
>
> rm /var/tmp/aws-mon/instance-id

Remove the cache or wait six hours.

Also the CloudWatch monitoring script is deprecated. Better to use CloudWatch agent instead of script for collecting the logs and metrics.

Comment: Hello Jyothish, I have already removed this file "rm /var/tmp/aws-mon/instance-id", and also new file is created with the new instance id.

Comment: what I am not getting is where form it is using the Singapore region as I have already changed the default region to Mumbai.

Comment: Or is there any way to mention the region name with this command? ./mon-put-instance-data.pl --mem-util --mem-used --mem-avail